# World championship 2021: Game 10: Why was it a draw?

Tags: draw, world-championship, knight-endgame, rook-and-minor-endgame

Game: https://lichess.org/broadcast/world-chess-championship-2021/game-10/RwhGwnPX

I assume that the players agreed for a draw because they are GMs and both are capable of playing perfect game. But I am learning and can't understand the perfect way to play so that it ends up in draw. Can someone please play it out?

Comment: They drew the game because they both had 5 pawns on the same side of the board with equal material in pieces.

Comment: @MissMulan At the beginning and even in so many positions, we can see material equality and complete symmetry. But why should those positions be accepted as draws? Can you play the rest of the game if you are so fluent to prove that it is a draw? (I am aware of 3 fold repetition)

Comment: I think I could hold this endgame against an engine by doing nothing. The only thing Black should *not* do is offering a knight exchange, because the white king is more active, and even that probably doesn't throw the draw.

Comment: As usual in most drawn endgames, the side who tries to win will lose it. Hence neither side will try to win, and no progress will be made.

Comment: It's really hard to get a win when all the pawns are on one side of the board.  For example, two pawns against three on the same side with rooks is a draw.

Comment: It doesn't require "perfect" play to make a draw. The draw was agreed because even if one of the players did a few inaccurate moves, there would be no way for his opponent to capitalize

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As has been mentionned already, it's a draw because with the symetrical pawn structure and only a knight and king left on the board, there is simply no way that either side can create a threat which the other side cannot counter with accurate play.  There are simply no deep ideas left in the position which a grandmaster at Ian and Magnus' levels wouldn't imediately see through and guard against.

As far as playing out the game, here's [a link](https://www.chess.com/analysis/game/pgn/4Zb1spHr8E) to one of Stockfish's suggested move patterns (depth=20).

```
[FEN "8/pp6/2pk1n2/3pN3/3P4/2P1K3/PP6/8 b - - 0 1"]

1... Ke6 {0.00} 2. a3 {0.00} 2... Ne4 3. c4 {0.00} 3... Kd6 4. Kd3 {0.00} 4... Ke6 5. b4 {0.00} 5... a6 6. c5 a5 {0.00} 7. bxa5 Nxc5+ {0.00} 8. Kc3 Ne4+ 9. Kb4 c5+ {0.00} 10. dxc5 Kxe5 11. c6 Kd6 12. cxb7 Kc7 {0.00} 13. a6 Nd6 14. Kc5 Nxb7+ 15. axb7 Kxb7 {0.00} 16. a4 Ka6 17. Kxd5 Ka5 18. Kc5 Kxa4 19. Kd4 Kb4 {0.00} 20. Ke5 {0.00} 20... Ka3 {0.00} 1/2-1/2
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Small addendum: I also tried to play out, but fifth-best (Lichess/Stockfish) of Black against best of White instead (well, no moves that outright hang material). Even with outright idiotic play (fixing a weakness on a6 and ending up with a stranded Ng8) I managed only +0.5.